# Cannot query nvarchar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, arabic, cjk

I have one table in sql db where I store nvarchar values

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Buns]
    (
        [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        
        [ARABIC] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
        [ENGLISH] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
        
    )
```

I can query the English values only

Appreciate your support with clear steps as am still a beginner

Comment: avoid screenshots , paste your sample code/data as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify an `nvarchar` string literal, you need to prefix it with `N`:

```
SELECT ARABIC, JAPANESE, ENGLISH
FROM dbo.Buns
WHERE ARABIC = N'قيمة للبحث عنها'
```